# when the windows font changes size

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts

I'm using Delphi 7. The machine I use to compile my application has the windows system font size - configured in display properties - set larger than any typical machine set to default.

The problem I have is the background panel of which the form is its parent is way oversized.

Comment: Does setting form.Scaled property to false help?

Comment: Please can you ask a question

Comment: This question might give a clue, [`How do I make my GUI behave well when Windows font scaling is greater than 100%`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8296784/576719).

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "font scaling" and "higher than 96 DPI".  You probably have `TForm.Scaled = true` on your main form and are seeing some behaviour that looks wrong.  Try to ask a real question, include a picture, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure AutoScroll property of your form is set to False, and Scaled = True. Also Delphi 7 tends to set AutoScroll to True each time you open the project.