# Disable form resizing without borders

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to disable the form resizing but I am not succeeding , my problem is that the components are misaligning in large resolutions.how can I prevent the form to resize with the style of the border = bsnone ?

Comment: Form with `bsNone` style cannot be resized (as long as you explicitly write some code for that). So, what's the problem ?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE so that we don't have to guess what you have done. Please also read the help section of this site (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to learn more about how to ask better questions.

Comment: @TLama, the OP probably means that when borderstyle is bsNone, some components scale out of the form. Common problem with dialogs (even Emb has released some IDE versions where you could not fill in some fields or press some buttons).

Comment: Some background reading, [How do I make my GUI behave well when Windows font scaling is greater than 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8296784/576719).

Comment: @LURD It sucks that the accepted answer there advises that DPI scaling is too hard to achieve.

Comment: may be you want to turn off scalling for high DPI resolution?

Comment: @Zam I guess you'd also need to move the screens much closer to your face

Comment: We have an application with hundreds of forms, and achieving DPI awareness was done in a matter of a couple weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using DelphiXE compiler or higher, you could use **Ancors**. If using a lower compiler version this will fail at higher DPI setting.

Also you may want to check out **Align** and **AlignWithMargins**.