# Can I use TTaskBar in non High-DPI aware application?

Tags: delphi

I build a MDI (`FormStyle = fsMDIForm`) VCL application in `Delphi 10 Seattle Update 1`. I disable High-DPI and running the following code:

```
var F: TForm;
    B: TTaskBar;
begin
  F := TForm.Create(Application);
  F.FormStyle := fsMDIChild;

  B := TTaskBar.Create(F);
  B.TabProperties := [TThumbTabProperty.CustomizedPreview];
end;
```

I run the application on Windows 8.1 with multi monitor support with these settings:

1. Primary Display 0: 1920 x 1080 resolution
2. Display 1: 1366 x 768 resolution
3. In `Control Panel | Display`, uncheck `Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays` and
4. `Change the size of all items` to scale other than `smaller`(`96` dpi) (e.g.: Middle - `120` dpi or Larger `144` dpi)

The application will raise `Failed to set bitmap as preview` exception when I move mouse pointer over to button on windows task bar.

If I enable the High DPI aware in `Project | Option`, it works fine.

Is TTaskBar not suitable for non High-DPI aware application?

Comment: Have you considered debugging this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have tried debug, but no clue at all. It fail at `LResult := DwmSetIconicThumbnail(GetFormHandle, FTmpPreviewBitmap.Handle, 0);`

Comment: What is the HRESULT error code? Read MSDN docs. Try to understand the API.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `HRESULT is -2147024809` MSDN only mentioned this: `If this function succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code.`  Couldn't find meaning for the error code.

Comment: Convert it to hex and then decode it. Do a websearch to understand how to decode. Take this opportunity to gain some skills. FWIW I guess that the framework is making a preview of the wrong size.

Comment: FWIW, that `HResult` value is [`E_INVALIDARG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: As Remy said, this component is poor. Far better to use the raw API which is easy enough to use.

Comment: @TOndrej: I use `CheckOSError` and it prompt `One or more arguments are not valid`

Comment: @ChauCheeYang Yes, that message corresponds to the `HResult` value, also shown on the page I linked to.

Comment: Try some debugging. Work out why this function is being called. What contract must it adhere to. Why is it failing? What changes with and without dpi awareness? This is all documented. Sure we could do that for you but I feel that you are capable of this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have rephrase my question.  The error happens on  specific environment setting: MDI application and DPI = `120` or more

Comment: Why are you creating a (long deprecated) MDI application in the 21st century? That's 1980s. This is nearly 2016. No one has used MDI for twenty years, and it's only around now in Windows for backwards-compatibility reasons. It's no wonder it doesn't work properly now in current Windows versions.

Comment: @KenWhite: The taskbar issue isn't fully related to MDI application.  The method `TCustomTaskbar.DoThumbPreviewRequest` get form image from MDI child form explicitly.  Even if I handle the event `TTaskBar.OnThumbPreviewRequest`, I will render the thumbnail image similarly regardless of it's formstyle and I will face the same issue too.

Comment: Why won't you debug this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have tried to debug it. I found out two parameters: `APreviewHeight` and `APreviewWidth` in method `procedure TCustomTaskbar.DoThumbPreviewRequest` is the one that cause the error.  If I reduce both parameters to `APreviewHeight := MulDiv(APreviewHeight, 96, 120)`, than it works.  I think it was the size that cause the error to method `DwmSetIconicThumbnail`.  The value of `96` and `120` is the default PPI and monitor's PPI respectively.

Comment: That tallies with what I said yesterday, "I guess that the framework is making a preview of the wrong size."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. Thanks David.  At least I found the cause the problem.  Now, next problem arise,  The problem happens on non High-DPI aware application.  How can I detect the current DPI setting for my display. `Screen.monitors[n].PIxelPerInch` all shows `96` in my case.  The only way I found so far is access registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\AppliedDPI` to get the value.  Is there a windows API to return actual screen DPI from non High-DPI runtime?

Comment: That question has been asked many times here. A search will find it.

Comment: The best answer I found so far is using registry from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\AppliedDPI` but not API in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983837/getting-custom-dpi-percentage-in-delphi